# is there anyway to conditionally render a React component once or more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This Question is NOT same as:
React: How to render a component twice in a page?

Please actually read the question!!!!!!!!

This question is for conditional for more than one pages! another question is for a fixed time.

I have a component build in ReactmyComponent.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('my-id')
);
```

This component will be used in multiple html, in some page I want to render it once, in some, it need to render twice:

page1.html

```
<div id='my-id'></div>
```

page2.html

```
<div id='my-id'></div>
<div>some other html</div>
<div id='my-id'></div>
```

Is there anyway to render the component once or twice conditional for different html page?

Comment: You cannot have multiple DOM elements with the same ID, but yes, you can render it wherever you like, and as many times as you like

Comment: What above says its true, but doesnt answer the question. Normally you do something like (page1 === somestate){render(){componentOfYourLiking}}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, components may be rendered conditionally.

Inside your `render() {}` method you can do something like...

```
render() {
    if (condition1) {
        return (<Component1 id="my-id" />);
    } else 
    if (condition2) {
        return (<Component2 id="my-id" />);
    } else {
        return (<Component3 id="my-id" />);
    }
}
```

Or if you need multiple components you can just as easily place them in the same return block, assuming you wrap them with a div (or some other element).

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Component1 className="my-className-1" />
            <Component2 className="my-className-2" />
            <Component3 className="my-className-3" />
            <Component1 className="my-className-1" />
            <Component2 className="my-className-2" />
            <Component3 className="my-className-3" />
            <Component1 className="my-className-1" />
            <Component2 className="my-className-2" />
            <Component3 className="my-className-3" />
            ... 
            // You can do as many as you like,
            // components here do not need to be unique.
        </div>
    );
}
```

Lastly, also make sure that you use your HTML `id` attribute as a unique identifier and HTML `class` attribute with multiple components. (JSX uses `className` btw)

Comment: My question is it possible to conditionally render 1 component once or more than once in a page

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? I provided an example of how you may use conditions to render components. I also provided an example of using the same component multiple times. So just put these two examples together? If this does not help I would suggest editing your question as it isn't very clear what you are asking.

Comment: Never do multiple returns in the render method. React crawls down the components tree for every change. Please refer to this article: https://medium.com/@cowi4030/optimizing-conditional-rendering-in-react-3fee6b197a20

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to build out constants with the code that want.

So page 1 will need to be something like:

```
const componentPage1 = (
  <div id='my-id'></div>
)
```

and page 2 similar.

You can then use JSX to solve this. JSX will allow you to add Javascript for your conditional statement of whether x === 1:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    {x === 1
    ? componentPage1
    : componentPage2
  },
  document.getElementById('my-id')
);
```